# If p is an odd prime, then any prime that divides $2^{p}-1$ is congruent to $\pm 1$ (mod 8).

Tags: number-theory

Question: If p is an odd prime, then any prime that divides $2^{p}-1 $ is congruent to $\pm 1$ (mod 8).
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime#Theorems_about_Mersenne_numbers

On the linked wikipedia article it gives a proof using the quadratic reciprocity but i dont have such a tool at my disposal. can this be proved somehow without using that fact?

Comment: use fermat's little theorem

Comment: i dont understand.

Comment: @James How should this help ? We can only prove $q\equiv 1\mod p$ this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see an easier way to prove it than to prove that particular supplement to the quadratic reciprocity. That proof is rather simple, however.

First we note that if $q$ is a prime dividing $2^p - 1$, then $2$ is a quadratic residue modulo $q$. This follows from the fact that the order of $2$ modulo $q$ is odd, or one can immediately write $2^{p+1} \equiv 2 \pmod{q}$, and $p+1$ is even.

Now we show that if $q$ is an odd prime such that there is a $\zeta$ with $\zeta^2 \equiv 2 \pmod{q}$, then $q \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{8}$. By [Thue's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue's_lemma), there are positive integers $x,y < \sqrt{q}$ such that $x \equiv \pm \zeta\cdot y \pmod{q}$. Then $x^2 - 2y^2$ is a multiple of $q$. Since $0 < x,y < \sqrt{q}$, we have

$$-2q < x^2 - 2y^2 < q,$$

and $x^2 - 2y^2 = 0$ is impossible since $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational. Thus $x^2 - 2y^2 = -q$. Since $-q$ is odd, it follows that $x$ must be odd, and hence $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$. If $y$ is even, then $2y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{8}$, and $$-q = x^2 - 2y^2 \equiv x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{8}.$$

If $y$ is odd, then $y^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$ and

$$-q = x^2 - 2y^2 \equiv 1 - 2\cdot 1 \equiv -1 \pmod{8}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $q$ an odd prime with $q|2^p-1$. We have $$2^p\equiv1\pmod q\iff2^{p+1}\equiv 2\pmod q\iff2^{\frac{p+1} {2}}\equiv\sqrt2\pmod q$$ Since $p$ is odd, $p+1$ is even so $2$ is a square modulo $q$.

In this case, by the quadratic reciprocity law we have $$\left(\frac 2q\right)=(-1)^{\dfrac {q^2-1}{8}}=1$$ Therefore $q$ is congruent with $\pm1$ modulo 8.

ILLUSTRATIVE NOTE.- Among the first nine odd primes $2^p-1$, six are Mersenne primes and only for $11,23$ and $29$ we have composite numbers: We have

$$2^{11}-1=(8\cdot3-1)(8\cdot11+1)\\2^{23}-1=(8\cdot6-1)(8\cdot22310+1)\\2^{29}-1=(8\cdot29+1)(8\cdot138-1)(8\cdot261+1)$$